# Sharing an object across multiple vbscript instances (for ADO connection pooling)

Tags: object, com, vbscript, activex, ado

Is there *any* way to share an object reference (not value) across multiple VBS applications? It seems like an out-of-process COM object might work, but that puts me in way over my head, and I'd like to know if I'm barking up the wrong tree before I spend a week pounding my head on it.

The background: I'm forced by the product I'm using to communicate with my database using a bunch of small vb scripts, each called independently (there's no way around this). This means dozens of individual connections per minute to the database (one connection per script). Rather than flog it this way (constantly establishing new connections), I'd love to figure out if there's a way for a standalone program to define and open the ADO Connection object, and then have that standalone program share the Connection object with all the little vb scripts (so that connection pooling kicks in).

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: These VBScripts, are they being executed in the same process or is the cscript.exe being run "dozens of times" per minute?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware VB script allows passing parameters by reference.  I assume it also allows the references to be returned from functions.

I think your idea may work, and is probably worth a try.

Create a COM Application or library using a language such as VB (as opposed to VBScript) or Delphi which could as you suggest connect to the Database and hold an ADODB connection?  Then define a method on that object that is exposed via COM that returns the ADODB connection as an OLEVariant or simple Variant from a function

Something Like

```
function getConnection() as Object
```

I really don't know if this will work but it should.